How to break a string over Literal Block Scalar in Ansible
I have a variable in YAML script like that:
variable: |
  This is really long long line ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  And this line is not really long ---------
  And I am just chilling here

I want to validate all my scripts through YAMLLint, so I have to break the first line in two without changing its contents.
How can I achieve this?
If I try to define it literally, I am getting something like this:
variable: "\
  This is really long long line ---------------------\
  ------------------------------------------------------\n
  And this line is not really long ---------\n
  And I am just chilling here"

I am getting something like this (note the spaces in the second 2 lines):
  This is really long long line ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   And this line is not really long ---------
   And I am just chilling here

And other options just doesn't work. How do I obey YAMLLint rules in this sutuation?

Is something from How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines? working? You'll probably need to test some of the given options there.

You are seeing this behaviour because you are explicitly adding newlines, and then, adding a carriage return for the rest of the text.
You can go around this multiple ways:

Add the carriage return before the explicit newline:
variable: "\
  This is really long long line ---------------------\
  ------------------------------------------------------
  \nAnd this line is not really long ---------
  \nAnd I am just chilling here"


Use a blank line to add a newline:
variable: "\
  This is really long long line ---------------------\
  ------------------------------------------------------

  And this line is not really long ---------

  And I am just chilling here"


Use a Jinja comment to control whitespaces:
variable: |
  This is really long long line ---------------------{#- -#}
  ------------------------------------------------------
  And this line is not really long ---------
  And I am just chilling here



All the above would give you the expected and would pass an ansible-lint test:
This is really long long line ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
And this line is not really long ---------
And I am just chilling here

